# Change type columns on Adminhtml Magento 2

Tags: magento2, adminhtml

I've got a table for my own module, and i want to change the type of the column that i added.

My render looks like:

```
protected function _prepareToRender()
    {
        $this->addColumn('code', ['label' => __('Code'), 'style' => 'width:120px']);

        $this->addColumn('cost', ['label' => __('Extra Cost'), 'style' => 'width:120px']);

        $this->addColumn('shopavailable', ['label' => __('Delivery'), 'type' => 'checkbox' , 'style' => 'width:320px']);

        $this->addColumn('none', ['label' => __('None'), 'style' => 'width:320px']);

        $this->_addButtonLabel = __('Add Attribute');
    }
```

I was trying to set it by using 'type' but i couldnt.

Any idea of how could set to this column a type checkbox or boolean?